# Adding support for Zip files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, zip, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2

Hadoop by default have a support for reading .gz compressed files, I want to have similar support for .zip files. I should be able to read content of zip files by using hadoop -text command.

I am looking for an approach where I dont have to implement inputformat and recordreader for zip files. I want my jobs to be completely agnostic of the format of the input files, it should work irrespective of whether the data is zipped  or unzipped. Similar  to how it is for.gz files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop streaming with zip input files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257447/hadoop-streaming-with-zip-input-files)

Comment: no its not a duplicate of that I am not looking for Inputformat and recordreader solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that I only see two ways to do this from "within" hadoop, either using a custom inputformat and recordreader based on `ZipInputStream` (which you clearly specified you were not interested in) or by detecting `.zip` input files and unzipping them before launching the job.

I would personally do this from outside hadoop, converting to gzip (or LZO indexed if I needed splittable files) via a script before running the job, but you most certainly already thought about that...

I'm also interested to see if someone can come up with an unexpected answer.